# Neural network output on MNIST converges to zero, regardless of input

Tags: python, neural-network

After reading through [Iamtrask's guide on programming a simple NN in python](https://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/), I made an attempt at rewriting one as a simple class so I could pick the layer count and sizes and apply it do different problems more easily.

After some finagling, it reached a point where it does a wonderful job on the example in that tutorial, and on other simple things like Binary Numbers <<>> Gray Code conversion, so I figured I'd go for something less simple with the MNIST handwritten digits dataset.

Unfortunately, this is where I'm stumped. After the first couple generations, the output layer always approaches something like

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

thaaat. They never all fully *reach* zero, but the result is that **no matter the input, it ends up guessing the same digit** because one of the output nodes is *just* slightly further from zero than the rest. I tried adding more nodes to the two hidden layers until Python told me enough was enough, tried doing it with just one hidden layer, and the result never really gets any better.

At first, I figured I must've misunderstood something fundamental about backpropagation, but then why does my NN adjust perfectly fine on the simpler problems? What is it I'm missing here, and how can I fix it to reach any useful result?

Here's my code for the neural network class (72 lines):

```
import numpy as np

class neuralNetwork():

    def __init__(self, layer_node_counts):
        self.synapses = self.init_synapses(layer_node_counts)

    def init_synapses(self, layer_node_counts):
        last_layer_node_count = layer_node_counts[0]
        synapses = []

        for current_layer_node_count in layer_node_counts[1:]:
            synapses.append(2* np.random.random((last_layer_node_count, current_layer_node_count)) - 1)
            last_layer_node_count = current_layer_node_count
        return synapses

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))

    def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(self, x):
        # kind of a bell curve!
        return x*(1-x)

    def feed_forward(self, input_):
        # forward propagation through all our synapses and layers, starting with the input array:
        layers = [np.array(input_)]

        for key, synapse in enumerate(self.synapses):
            newLayer = self.sigmoid(layers[key] @ synapse)
            layers.append(newLayer)

        return layers

    def classify(self, input_):
        resulting_layers = self.feed_forward(input_)
        # return output layer(s)
        return resulting_layers[-1]

    def train(self, input_, target_output):
        input_ = np.atleast_2d(input_)
        target_output = np.atleast_2d(target_output)

        layer_result_matrices = self.feed_forward(input_)
        synapse_adjustments_total = [0] * len(self.synapses)

        # how much this layer was off the mark
        output_error = target_output - layer_result_matrices[-1]
        # how much we're letting it matter (bell curve height - depends on "confidence" of the synapse connection)
        output_delta = output_error * self.sigmoid_derivative(layer_result_matrices[-1])

        layer_deltas = [output_delta]

        for index in reversed(range(1, len(self.synapses))):
            layer_error = layer_deltas[0] @ self.synapses[index].T
            layer_delta = layer_error * self.sigmoid_derivative(layer_result_matrices[index])
            layer_deltas.insert(0, layer_delta)

        for index in range(len(self.synapses)):
            synapse_adjustments_total[index] += layer_result_matrices[index].T @ layer_deltas[index]

        for index, adjustment in enumerate(synapse_adjustments_total):
            self.synapses[index] += adjustment

        return self.synapses

    def calculate_mean_error(self, input_, target_output):
        current_output = self.classify(input_)

        error_matrix = np.abs(target_output - current_output) / len(target_output)
        mean_error = np.mean(np.abs(error_matrix))

        return mean_error
```

...and my code for training (64 lines):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import nekkowe_neural_network as nnn
from mnist import MNIST

def normalize_input(images):
    return np.array(images) / (255 * 0.99 + 0.01)

def get_one_hot_by_label(label):
    return [0.99 if i == label else 0.01 for i in range(10)]

def get_label_by_one_hot(layer):
    return np.argmax(layer)

def test_accuracy(neural_network, test_images, target_labels):
    guesses = 0
    correct_guesses = 0

    normalized_input = normalize_input(test_images)
    output_layers = neural_network.classify(normalized_input)

    for i, output_layer in enumerate(output_layers):        
        predicted_label = get_label_by_one_hot(output_layer)
        target_label    = target_labels[i]

        guesses += 1
        correct_guesses += 1 if predicted_label == target_label else 0

    print(str(correct_guesses) + "/" + str(guesses) + " correct")


BATCH_SIZE = 64
MAX_ITERATIONS = 1000

np.random.seed(1)
neural_network = nnn.neuralNetwork([28**2, 28**2, 28**2, 10])

mndata = MNIST('MNIST')

#training_data_images, training_data_labels = mndata.load_training()
#training_data_one_hot = [get_one_hot_by_label(label) for label in training_data_labels]

testing_data_images, testing_data_labels = mndata.load_testing()
training_data = mndata.load_training_in_batches(BATCH_SIZE)

for i, batch in enumerate(training_data):
    training_data_images = np.array(batch[0])
    training_data_labels = np.array(batch[1])
    training_data_one_hot = np.array([get_one_hot_by_label(label) for label in training_data_labels])

    if i > 0:
        neural_network.train(training_data_images, training_data_one_hot)

    # Report progress at 0, 1, 10, 100, 200, 300, 400 etc. as well as the final one:
    if i % 100 == 0 or np.log10(i) % 1 == 0 or i == MAX_ITERATIONS:
        print("Batch " + str(i) + ":")
        test_accuracy(neural_network, testing_data_images, testing_data_labels)

    if i == MAX_ITERATIONS:
        print("Reached iteration limit!")
        break

print("All done!")
```

Comment: Your `sigmoid_derivative` isn't what it should be.

Comment: @cheersmate I should definitely rephrase that function name - in the case where it's used, the input has already been passed through the regular `sigmoid`, so I figured doing it again would lead to the wrong result. [see also here](https://github.com/iamtrask/iamtrask.github.io/issues/12)

Comment: @cheersmate I have edited the function name to `sigmoid_output_to_derivative` for clarity, accordingly